# How to check if scrollbar value is pass some value?

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollbar

I have scrollBar in c# wpf and on some value on it a function have to be called. What is the fastest way for searching that values? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling in WPF is handled by the [`IScrollInfo` Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.iscrollinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The `ScrollViewer` class implements it and exposes some of its properties. You will need to access some of these properties to calculate whether the content has been scrolled to your certain point or not:

[image]

The [`ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.verticaloffset.aspx), [`ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.viewportheight.aspx) and [`ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight` Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.extentheight.aspx) are the most likely to help you in your endeavour (if you are measuring vertical scrolling). The `ViewPort` is the visible area of the scrolled content, the `Extent` is the total size of the scrolled content and the `Offset` properties show the offset of the scrolled content.

If you are not using a `ScrollViewer`, then I would recommend that you do because the `ScrollBar` class does not have these properties.